# Через какие .NET библиотеки можно хешировать строки в C#?

Tags: c#, хеширование, поиск-библиотек

Просьба дать также код для хеширования переменной str типа string.

Comment: У любого объекта в C# есть метод `GetHashCode()`

Comment: Так же можно воспользоваться MD5

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

string str;
byte[] tmpSource;
byte[] tmpHash;

//Считываем исходную строку
str = Console.ReadLine();
//Преобразовываем в битовые данные
tmpSource = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
//Вычисляем хэш
tmpHash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(tmpSource);
```